# Update summary statistics columns using field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, summarizing

I want to update 2 columns, which were made by summarizing field values in the first column (WEQ) based on spatial location. The summarized field (WEQ) has been updated using the field calculator, but now i want to manually update the statistic columns (WEQ_count & WEQ_sum) with the field calculator. This update would need to be grouped once again by object polygon (not uniquely indexed polygons).
Is there a way to do this, without needing to use the spatial summarize tool and without creating a new layer?

[image]

Comment: The geometries to group by are identical?

Comment: Not necessarily, the file is based on a neighborhood file, where the geometries are the buildings. And where entries in the attribute table represent adresses in the neighborhood, which can be multiple per building.